# Toggle button takes two clicks

Tags: javascript, css, express, handlebars.js

I have made a toggle button to show some navlinks on mobile screens.
However on the first page load it takes two clicks.
After that point it toggle perfectly fine.
How can I make it so it functions correctly first time?

Heres the script that contains the function.

script.js

```
function ToggleNavLinks() { /
    var navLink = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-links")[0]; 
    
    if (navLink.style.display === "none") { 
        navLink.style.display = "flex"; 
    } 
    else {
        navLink.style.display = "none"; 
    }
}
```

Heres the layout file that contains the front-end element.
I have tested if it was the external script reference and it definitely works.

layout.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>   

        <title>{{title}}</title>        

        <meta charset="utf-8"/> <!-- Charset -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/script.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar"> 
                <img class="logo" alt="logo" src="images/logo-stock.png">

                
                <a class="nav-toggle" onclick="ToggleNavLinks()" > 
                    <span class="bar"></span> 
                    <span class="bar"></span> 
                    <span class="bar"></span> 
                </a>

                <!-- Links used in the navbar -->
                <div class="nav-links"> 
                    <ul>
                        <li> 
                            <a href="#">Home</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li> 
                            <a href="#">Projects</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li> 
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        
        <div>
            {{{body}}} 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ill also include the stylesheet in case that has anything to do with it.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap'); 

:root { 
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
  --text-primary: white; 
  --text-secondary: #4c6bc1; 
  --bg-primary: #101316; 
  --bg-secondary: #181a1d; 
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body { 
  background-color: var(--bg-primary);
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.25rem;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track { 
  background: #181a1d; 
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { 
  background: #4c6bc1; 
}

.navbar {
  justify-content: space-between; 
  position: relative; 
  background-color: var(--bg-secondary); 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between; 
  align-items: center; 
}

.navbar img { 
  width: 250px; 
  height: 100px; 
}

.logo{ 
  max-width: 100%; 
  height: auto; 
}

.navbar-links { 
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-links ul { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  display: flex; 
}

.nav-links li { 
  list-style: none; 
}

.nav-links li a { 
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem; 
  display: block; 
}

.nav-links li a:hover { 
  color: #4c6bc1; 
}

.nav-toggle { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem; 
  right: 1rem; 
  display: none; 
  flex-direction: column; 
  justify-content: space-between; 
  height: 21px; 
  width: 30px; 
}

.nav-toggle:hover { 
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.nav-toggle .bar { 
  height: 3px; 
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: white; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .nav-toggle { 
    display: flex;
  }

  .nav-links { 
    display: none;
    width: 100%; 
  }

  .navbar { 
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .nav-links ul { 
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .nav-links li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav-links.active { 
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Have you ensured your `navLink.style.display` is actually none on page load when you call `navLink.style.display = "none"; //Else leave display as none`? I'd bet the double click is because it isn't being assigned to flex because your conditional is wrong because you explicitly define it to be set to `none` in the else statement if it isn't that already....what is the value from the default?

Comment: Its set as none in the stylesheet

Comment: that doesn't mean `navlink.style.display` is equal to the string `none`. Check if `window.getComputedStyle(navlink).display === 'none'`. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Comment: So where would I put that into the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
element.style.display === 'none'
```

is true when the element has an inline `style` attribute, which includes `display: none`. Note that this is true **regardless** of the actual computed style property of the element. You can check it in this example:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.test').style.display);
```

```css
.test {
  display: block !important;
}
code {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: none;" class="test">I haz <code>style.display === 'none'</code>. You are looking at me. Stop staring, it's not nice.</div>
```

To check the computed property of the `display`, use

```
window.getComputedStyle(element).display === 'none'
```

---

In conclusion, replace

```
if (navLink.style.display === "none") {
```

with

```
if (window.getComputedStyle(navLink).display === "none") {
```

Answer (score 0):

It maybe not the problem of Your Javascript. First check your CSS file. Check if the order of your code i.e display tag is already none or flex. Then only it was not working at 1st instance.
It may be like that:

```
 .navlink{
display: none;
}
```

Change it to :

```
 .navlink{
display: flex;
}
```

Comment: That does fix it however the idea is that, that element should be display: none until the media query triggers.